# php jquery in the include page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, include

I am currently encountering a problem with PHP and jQuery. I have build a website like this:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    include('content.php');
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

content.php

```
test
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    });
</script>
```

but when the page load.. the alert is not working.. do i miss something?

Comment: Try `<?php include('content.php'); ?>` instead of `include('content.php');`

Comment: Upvoted. This is actually a good question for beginners. (But where is bootstrap?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two issues:

1. include('content.php');

this should be

```
<body>
<?php include('content.php'); ?>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

2. you are firing the jquery codes before jquery is loaded.

change like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('content.php'); ?>        
</body>
```